# Secure Coding Practices (.Net) is leaving it to the framework a wise idea?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Back in my developer days (circa 2011) I used stuff like the AntiXSS library to help build apps that were more secure.  I'm now informed by some of the dev's I'm working with that the .Net framework now "does a lot of this" out of the box - with the implication (as I saw it) that it may be an excuse to be lazy.

Laziness aside - is the .Net framework these days "enough" or should you still augment it with other security libraries?  And if so, which ones?

Update:

I'm not worried about any single specific threat; I want to know if relying on the .Net framework is considered good (or "good enough") practice.

FYR: Secure Coding Practices is "the practice of developing computer software in a way that guards against the accidental introduction of security vulnerabilities":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_coding
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Coding_Practices_-_Quick_Reference_Guide

An example of this would be to parse/validate input from users.

Comment: What kind of secure coding practices are you referring to?

Comment: Specifically, what kind of security issues are you worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if relying on the .Net framework is considered good (or
>   "good enough") practice.

If you are using the framework correctly, then yes, its implementation of various security features can be considered secure.

However, you must have a good understanding of the threat you are trying to mitigate to *know* that you are using the framework in the intended fashion. Security features often need to be enabled/configured to provide the desired security.

Examples:

- HTML encoding works "out of the box", but you can easily introduce double-encoded values or let user input slip past the encoding if you are aren't careful.
- ASP.Net doesn't validate that a user hasn't tampered with IDs/privileged values.
- Cookies can be set to HTTP-only and to require SSL, but you must write code for this.
- ASP.Net doesn't provide (that I'm aware) a way to sanitize HTML while still allowing benign markup. This may be a good use of a third party library.
- ASP.Net has a good anti-CRSF imeplementation, but you must actively use it in your code.
- In most cases, the framework doesn't stop you from circumventing it and doing something insecure.